# Node.js handling redirect (302) for http/s.request is failing to resolve promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

I am writing a small function to handle server to server http/s requests.
The problem is coming when I am handling redirects.

I have wrapped the request in a promise and 99.99% works as expected for all request types (http/s, get, post, put, delete etc) and resolves or rejects correctly given the input parameters however redirects are tripping me up.

When handling a 300 - 400 http response, I am aborting the request, recursively calling the function and rejecting that promise instance and logging out the results looks correct, but on the last call after a 200 response code is received, it isn't resolving the promise.

Here's the log from a call to: https://www.httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/5

```
302
Loc: http://www.httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/4 maxRedirects: 9
{"msg":"redirect"}
302
Loc: http://www.httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/3 maxRedirects: 8
302
Loc: http://www.httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/2 maxRedirects: 7
302
Loc: http://www.httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/1 maxRedirects: 6
302
Loc: http://www.httpbin.org/get maxRedirects: 5
200
{ status: 200,
  headers: '{"connection":"close","server":"meinheld/0.6.1","date":"Tue, 27 Jun 2017 06:28:54 GMT","content-type":"application/json","access-control-allow-origin":"*","access-control-allow-credentials":"true","x-powered-by":"Flask","x-processed-time":"0.00139999389648","content-length":"167","via":"1.1 vegur"}' }
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "www.httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "origin": "***.***.***.***", 
  "url": "http://www.httpbin.org/get"
}
```

and here is the function itself:

```
function gimme(requestOptions) {
    //** Validate request object properties and set defaults where required
    typeof requestOptions.url === 'undefined' || requestOptions.url === null ? requestOptions.url = null : requestOptions.url = requestOptions.url;
    typeof requestOptions.method === 'undefined' ? requestOptions.method = 'GET' : requestOptions.method = requestOptions.method.toUpperCase();
    typeof requestOptions.body === 'undefined' ? requestOptions.body = null : requestOptions.body = requestOptions.body;
    typeof requestOptions.contentType === 'undefined' ? requestOptions.contentType = 'form' : requestOptions.contentType = requestOptions.contentType;
    typeof requestOptions.followRedirect === 'undefined' ? requestOptions.followRedirect = true : requestOptions.followRedirect = requestOptions.followRedirect;
    typeof requestOptions.maxRedirects === 'undefined' ? requestOptions.maxRedirects = 10 : requestOptions.maxRedirects = requestOptions.maxRedirects;
    typeof requestOptions.timeout === 'undefined' ? requestOptions.timeout = 10000 : requestOptions.timeout = requestOptions.timeout;
    typeof requestOptions.rejectUnauthorized === 'undefined' ? requestOptions.rejectUnauthorized = false : requestOptions.rejectUnauthorized = requestOptions.rejectUnauthorized;

    //** Create request literal to populate and use with request call
    let requestObject = {};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //** No url no worky!
    if(requestOptions.url === null) reject(JSON.stringify({msg:'Missing url'}));

    //** If protocol is missing backfill
    if(requestOptions.url.search(/^http[s]?\:\/\//) == -1){
        requestOptions.url = 'http://' + requestOptions.url;
    }

    //** Parse the url and return and object
    let urlObject = url.parse(requestOptions.url);

    //** Populate the request object
    requestObject.method = requestOptions.method;
    requestObject.hostname = urlObject.host;
    requestObject.path = urlObject.path;

    //** if https set port 443 else port 80 ?? Deal with non-standard ports
    urlObject.protocol === 'https' ? requestObject.port = 443 : requestObject.port = 80;

    //** Set the protocol to use for request call and require the relevant lib
    const lib = urlObject.protocol === 'https' ? require('https') : require('http');

    //** If body in payload parse and set data accordingly
    if(requestOptions.body !== null) {
        if(requestObject.method === 'GET'){
            requestObject.path = requestObject.path + '?' + querystring.stringify(requestOptions.body);
        } else {
            //** Populate the data to send
            var postData = JSON.stringify(requestOptions.body);

            //** Set headers 
            switch (requestOptions.contentType){
                case 'json':
                    requestObject.headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Length': postData.length
                    };
                break;
                case 'form':
                    requestObject.headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Content-Length': postData.length
                    };
                break;
                default:
                    requestObject.headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Content-Length': postData.length
                    };
                break;
            };
        };
    };

        let req = lib.request(requestObject, function (response) {
            if(response.statusCode > 300 && response.statusCode < 400 && response.headers.location) { //** Detect a redirect
                requestOptions.url = response.headers.location;
                --requestOptions.maxRedirects;
                req.abort();
                gimme(requestOptions);
                reject(JSON.stringify({msg:'redirect'}));
                return;
            } else if(response.statusCode == 405) {
                reject(JSON.stringify({msg:'Method Not Allowed'}));
            } else {
                let requestResult = {
                    status: response.statusCode,
                    headers: JSON.stringify(response.headers)
                };
                console.log(requestResult);

                //** temporary data holder
                const body = [];

                response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    body.push(chunk);
                });

                //** do 
                response.on('end', function () {
                    let reqRes = body.join('');
                    resolve(reqRes);
                    return;
                });
            };
        })

        req.on('socket', function (socket) {
            socket.setTimeout(requestOptions.timeout);  
            socket.on('timeout', function() {
                req.abort();
                reject(JSON.stringify({msg:'timeout'}));
            });
        });

        req.on('error', function (e) {
            reject(e.code + ' ' + e.syscall);
        });

        if(typeof postData !== 'undefined' && postData !== null){
            req.write(postData);
        }
        req.end();
    });
};
```

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Cheers
George

Comment: the problem is that you reject the promise, you start a new `gimme` but **ignore** it's return value, so of course the only  promise that is returned to the caller is the first rejected one ... try `resolve(gimme(requestOptions));` as a quick hack

Comment: also `if(requestOptions.url === null) reject(JSON.stringify({msg:'Missing url'}));` is doomed for failure ... as there is no `reject` function at that point in the code

Comment: Cheers Jaromanda, yeah I was moving the new Promise... around in the hope that I was putting something out of scope. It was originally before the  //** No url no worky! line :)

I get your idea, but as you say, it feels "hacky" as at that point I have a 200 response and then re-request the same page again!

Comment: Jaromanda your comment led me to the answer.
Thanks again :)